# Problem with sincos() stack overflow, solution?

Tags: linux, gcc, stack-overflow

On Ubuntu 11.04, compiling software from source and then running it sometimes results in a stack overflow of repeated calls to sincos() *before* the app even starts.  Sometimes I can work around this issue by defining my own version of sincos().  Sometimes this does not work.

Is anyone else encountering this and is there a solution?

*Edit:*
The code is non-trivial.  I don't have access to the Ubuntu 11.04 machine at the moment either.  This problem drives me nuts, was hoping it was a known issue.

@sehe:  I am not sure, but this could be possible.

Comment: Can you tell where the first call originates?

Comment: Perhaps tell us about the stacktrace. Where is the trace? Could it be non-threadsafe initialization of static data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reported gcc bug related to `sincos`:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46926

Can you change the name to, for example, `sin_cos`?

Comment: I don't intend to have a function called sincos().  The page you mentioned seemed to describe the issue exactly.  Does this imply that there is a function sincos() buried in the source code somewhere?  *Edit:* A grep of the source code shows a third-party C library that defines its own version of sincos().  Could this be the culprit?

Comment: Probably.  You have the source (and we don't), so search it for the identifier `sincos` (`grep -rw source-dir sincos`).  As I understand it, conflicts with the internal glibc or gcc built-in function of the same name (though it shouldn't).

Comment: I'll try commenting out this function tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: There's a comment in the GCC bug report that implies that `sincos()` is a POSIX function - but I can't find it in the [POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson : removing the unneeded definition of sincos() from the code fixed it. Thanks!